# How to get visible bars on a histogram/distribution plot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've been using pandas and seaborn for data visualisation, but whenever I create a histogram/distribution plot, the bins aren't clearly defined, as in there are no lines separating the bins?

How do I fix this?

Thank you.